# Positioning side-effectful behavior in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I see in a project that side-effectful behavior is positioned inside actions like so:

```
// ...in ItemListPage.js
function onCreateItem (name, title, content) {
  this.props.dispatch(createItem({ name, title, content }));
};

// ...in ItemActions.js    
function createItem(post) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return callApi('items', 'create', {
      item: {
        name: post.name,
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content,
      },
    }).then(res => dispatch(addPost(res.post)));
  };
}
```

**Is the following an accurate description of what is gong on here?**

A function to be bound to an event from the Virtual DOM is created named `onCreateItem`.

When this function is run an action is dispatched to the store. The action is the result of invoking the action-creator(?) `createItem`. This action is a function-object that accepts a dispatcher.

Redux then runs the action (how does it know to do this?), passing in the dispatcher. The side-effectful logic is run (network call).

In this way the side-effectful logic is kept within the action function-object(?) and out of the reducers(?).

Is the promise returned from the action is swallowed - or can it be retrieved somehow?

What part of this code is using `redux-thunk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to understand this code is to understand what `redux-thunk` does and how (really) simple the Middleware is.

## Redux-thunk

Redux-thunk is a Middleware for redux which enhance redux with the ability to accept `function` actions. By default redux only accepts simple objects (that is not class objects nor functions) and then it dispatch said actions to all of the  reducers in the store. What redux-thunk does is intercepting action which are functions and invokes then with a reference to the dispatch method (these actions are **not** dispatched to reducers), that's it it's that simple.

## Your example

In your example situation is a bit more complex since we have (I assume) an async call to an external api endpoint. Let's go through it as the execution flows from the user interaction with the control to the item.

1. User interaction - some user interaction raises the `onCreateActoin` event handler, in turn this
2. Invokes the action creator creator `createAction`.
3. The created action (a function with the signature: `(reducer) => promise` is passed to `store.dispatch`.
4. The action is passed down the Middleware chain.
5. Redux-thunk catches the action and calls the function with one parameter - `reducer`.
6. The function creates a new `Promise` via `callApi`.
7. You add a listener to the promise on success (`.then`).
8. The promise is returned.
9. Redux-thunk breaks the Middleware chain, terminating any additional processing of the action.
10. The returned `promise` bubbles up and is returned by the original `dispatch` call (in `onCreateAction`)
11. (async) `callApi`'s promise finishes.
12. (async) the `then` we added is called.
13. (async) `addPost` is called and the result is passed to `store.dispatch`.

Comment: Thank you. Without redux-thunk, where would the async stuff be placed in a redux application?

Comment: @Ben with pure redux, nowhere obvious. By default redux will reject anything that is not an object with prototype `object`. So both functions and Promises will be rejected. You could in theory wrap promises in an action object that looks like `{ type, promise}` but then you wouldn't be able to return the promise to the original caller anr you'd have to dispatch from the reducer, which is not recommended. In reality it is either you spin your own function calling Middleware or you use redux-thunk (or equivalents)